# How to convert an array of multiple entries into an object with key?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to convert an array of multiple entries into an object with key?

```js
const A03 = [];
const animals = [
['Name01', '5/21/2021 18:00:00', 'SecA'],
['Name02', '5/21/2021 18:00:00', 'SecA'],
['Name03', '5/21/2021 18:00:00', 'SecB'],
['Name04', '5/21/2021 18:00:00', 'SecB']
];
['SecA', 'SecB'].forEach(li => {
const newArr = animals.filter(x => x[2] === li).reduce((a, [Name, DOB, Sec]) => {
    a[Name] = {
        Name,
        DOB,
        Sec
    };
    return a;
}, {});
A03.push(newArr);
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(A03));
```

And I'm getting output result as below:

```
[{
  "Name01": { "Name": "Name01", "DOB": "5/21/2021 18:00:00", "Sec": "SecA" },
  "Name02": { "Name": "Name02", "DOB": "5/21/2021 18:00:00", "Sec": "SecA" }
},
{
  "Name03": { "Name": "Name03", "DOB": "5/21/2021 18:00:00", "Sec": "SecB" },
  "Name04": { "Name": "Name04", "DOB": "5/21/2021 18:00:00", "Sec": "SecB" }
}]
```

And required out is :

```
{
  "SecA": {
    "Name01": { "Name": "Name01", "DOB": "5/21/2021 18:00:00", "Sec": "SecA" },
    "Name02": { "Name": "Name02", "DOB": "5/21/2021 18:00:00", "Sec": "SecA" }
  }
},
{
  "SecB": {
    "Name03": { "Name": "Name03", "DOB": "5/21/2021 18:00:00", "Sec": "SecB" },
    "Name04": { "Name": "Name04", "DOB": "5/21/2021 18:00:00", "Sec": "SecB" }
  }
}
```

How do I need to customize the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple destructing and a loop. Using reduce() is overkill

```js
const animals = [
  ['Name01', '5/21/2021 18:00:00', 'SecA'],
  ['Name02', '5/21/2021 18:00:00', 'SecA'],
  ['Name03', '5/21/2021 18:00:00', 'SecB'],
  ['Name04', '5/21/2021 18:00:00', 'SecB'],
];

const grouped = {};

animals.forEach(([Name, DOB, Sec]) => {  
  const o = grouped[Sec] = grouped[Sec] || {};
  o[Name] = {Name, DOB, Sec};
});


console.log(grouped)
```

Answer (score 1):

I used [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#array_destructuring) to make code more readable:

```js
const animals = [
['Name01', '5/21/2021 18:00:00', 'SecA'],
['Name02', '5/21/2021 18:00:00', 'SecA'],
['Name03', '5/21/2021 18:00:00', 'SecB'],
['Name04', '5/21/2021 18:00:00', 'SecB']
];

const output = {};

for (const [name, date, sec] of animals) {
  if (!output[sec]) {
    output[sec] = {};
  }
  
  output[sec][name] = {
    Name: name,
    DOB: date,
    sec: sec
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

You do not have to hardcode `SecA` or `SecB` here. This will logically group based on the 2nd element of the array.

```js
const animals = [['Name01', '5/21/2021 18:00:00', 'SecA'],
        ['Name02', '5/21/2021 18:00:00', 'SecA'],
        ['Name03', '5/21/2021 18:00:00', 'SecB'],
        ['Name04', '5/21/2021 18:00:00', 'SecB']];
    
    let result = {}
    
    animals.forEach( (x) => {
        if (result[x[2]] === undefined) {
            result[x[2]]  = {}
        }
        result[x[2]] [x[0]] = { Name: x[0], DOB: x[1], Sec: x[2] };
    })
    
    console.log(result)
```

Comment: YoI should go with @Alizadeh118 as his answer is more readable

Answer (score 0):

also try this solution if it works for you

```js
const animals = [
  ["Name01", "5/21/2021 18:00:00", "SecA"],
  ["Name02", "5/21/2021 18:00:00", "SecA"],
  ["Name03", "5/21/2021 18:00:00", "SecB"],
  ["Name04", "5/21/2021 18:00:00", "SecB"],
];

let result = animals.reduce((acc, anim) => {
  const [, , sec] = anim;

  if (!acc[sec]) {
    acc[sec] = {
      [anim[0]]: anim,
    };
  } else {
    acc[sec] = { ...acc[sec], [anim[0]]: anim };
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);


// output

{
  SecA: {
    Name01: [ 'Name01', '5/21/2021 18:00:00', 'SecA' ],
    Name02: [ 'Name02', '5/21/2021 18:00:00', 'SecA' ]
  },
  SecB: {
    Name03: [ 'Name03', '5/21/2021 18:00:00', 'SecB' ],
    Name04: [ 'Name04', '5/21/2021 18:00:00', 'SecB' ]
  }
}
```